# How to make my protobuf objects pickle-able?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, apache-beam

I have this protobuf file called `HistogramBins.proto` like this:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

message HistogramBins {
  string field_name = 1;
  repeated float bins = 2;
}
```

which I compile it this way:

```
protoc --python_out=. ./HistogramBins.proto
```

And this will generate a file called `HistogramBins_pb2.py` for me. Then I'll try to serialize an Apache Beam stream using this class:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from components.HistogramBins_pb2 import HistogramBins
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class ToProtoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, t):
    hBin = HistogramBins()
    hBin.field_name = t[0]
    hBin.bins.extend(t[1])
    print(hBin)
    yield hBin


with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
    input_collection = (
        p
        | 'Read input data' >> beam.Create([("f1", [1.0, 2.0]), ("f2", [3.0, 4.0])])
        | 'record to HistogramBins' >> beam.ParDo(ToProtoFn())
        | beam.io.WriteToText('data/test2.pbtxt',
                              coder=beam.coders.ProtoCoder(HistogramBins().__class__))
    )
```

But fails with the following error message (this is the final line):

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'HistogramBins_pb2.HistogramBins'>: it's not found as HistogramBins_pb2.HistogramBins
```

This is while the following example works just fine. This time, I'm using a protobuf from Google package:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class ToProtoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    timestamp = Timestamp()
    timestamp.seconds, timestamp.nanos = [int(x) for x in element.strip().split(',')]
    print(timestamp)
    yield timestamp


with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
  lines = (p
      | beam.Create(["1586753000,222333000", "1586754000,222333000"])
      | beam.ParDo(ToProtoFn())
      | beam.io.WriteToText('time-pb',
                            coder=beam.coders.ProtoCoder(Timestamp().__class__)))
```

What is the difference between my protobuf and theirs?

This is Google's protobuf file:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package google.protobuf;

option csharp_namespace = "Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes";
option cc_enable_arenas = true;
option go_package = "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp";
option java_package = "com.google.protobuf";
option java_outer_classname = "TimestampProto";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option objc_class_prefix = "GPB";

message Timestamp {
  int64 seconds = 1;
  int32 nanos = 2;
}
```

Comment: It's more like an import problem than a complex class that cannot be pickled problem.

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution to your problem?